# How to exclude/ignore prop in class-validator

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-validator

I have a custom class with some properties that gets validated by a method in the same class. Then I sets the errors to a field. But when I returning those errors in json it gives me an Circular error on that error field.

```
export class UserValidator {
constructor(user: User) {
this.firstName = user.firstName;
this.lastName = user.lastName;
}

async validate(): Promise<boolean> {
return validate(this)
  .then((errors) => {
    this.err = errors;
  })
  .then(() => {
    return this.err.length === 0;
  });
}
privat err: ValidationError[];

2,25
firstName: string;

@Length(2,25)
lastName: string;
}

let userValidator = new UserValidator(user);
let valid = await userValidator.validate();

if (!valid) {
  throw new Error(userValidator.err);
}
```

It gives me this error:
 UserInputValidator {
       firstName: 'a',
       lastName: 'a',
       err: [Circular] },

Comment: I don't understand how this code can produce that output.  Please make sure you have posted the code that you are actually using.  I see multiple things that can't be right, including the reference to the private `err` field from outside the class.

Comment: I did simplify it, perhaps I missed some syntax that isn't valid. When I tried to fix my circular problem to work I had method to access the private err prop instead of have a public err prop. However it didn't work, and I missed to change it here

Comment: I can't help you based on the code you've provided.  If you want help, please post [code that is sufficient to reproduce the problem for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).